# Node.js + Express: Save the user and password in the browser

Tags: node.js, cookies, browser, authentication, express

I'm learning Node.JS with Express, now I'm working in the login form, all is right but when I login, the browser never save my Username and Password. How can I do it?

My App configuration for SESSION is this

```
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.cookieParser());
app.use(express.session({ key: 'session', secret: 'log', store: new express.session.MemoryStore }));
```

Then I use the `req.body.username` and `req.body.password` to authenticate. Finally I save de ID SESSION in `req.session.user_id`.

Thanks for the help. I don't know if is safe to save this things in the browser, but I'm thinking in the user.

Comment: You want the browser's own password save options?  If so, just put a password field on a page.

Comment: Mmm maybe the problem is because I'm using Ajax to login, after check it the javascript use `window.location.href` to the main page.

Comment: Yes, that will do it.  If you actually submit the form to go to the next page, then the user will be prompted.